# How to backup Thunderbird using the GUI menu?

Tags: backup, gui, email, thunderbird, mozilla

When going through the menu, I only see an option to back up the profile for `Thunberdird` whereas I want to backup e-mail.  Version:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ thunderbird --version
Thunderbird 115.4.1
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

From `tools` how is the backup e-mail option selected?

Comment: Tools > [Export](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-export) (*lets you create a backup of your Thunderbird profile including accounts, messages, address books, and settings*)... And there is an [ImportExportTools NG](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools-ng/) add-on (*adds import and export functions for messages, folders and profiles*) ... Both should work.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do backups in Thunderbird from the GUI ...

The **first** being the native [**Export**](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-export) option under the **Tools** menu ... It lets you create a backup of your Thunderbird profile including accounts, messages, address books and settings in the form of a ZIP file and save it locally in the target directory of your choice... That option, however, is limited to profile sizes not more that  2 GB.

The **second** is via the [ImportExportTools NG](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools-ng/) add-on that you need to install first, then you'll have an **ImportExportTools NG** sub-menu under the **Tools** menu as well from which you can choose the **Backup** option and follow the instruction ... It also has an automated backup scheduling feature that you can set at *Tools > ImportExportTools N > Options*.

Comment: After I lost important data, the limitations of Tbird forced me to consider alternatives.  Evolution has the best backup/restore routines and are not limited to number or sizes of files. Another email client is Clawsmail.